# Configure Nginx for Drupal 7, recursive directory?

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, drupal-7

I need to configure nginx for Drupal but i have many site in many level directory, only with one nginx server and name server (DNS).

Example:

/var/www -> List folders

/var/www/site1 -> Drupal site

/var/www/gorup -> List folders

/var/www/group/site2 -> Drupal site

/var/www/group/site3 -> Drupal site

Comment: Why my question have downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create symbolic link with structure folder you wish